# How to access global constructor when you override a variant?

Tags: ocaml

I have this code

```
module Ignore = struct
  type double_asterisk = 
    | None
    | Leading of string
    | Trailing of string
    | Middle of string * string

  let double_asterisk (line:string) : double_asterisk =
    let open Re in
    let matches pat line =
      exec_opt pat line in
    let middle = matches @@ Perl.compile_pat {|^(.*?)/*\*\*/*(.*?)$|} in 
    let leading = matches @@ Perl.compile_pat {|^\*\*/*(.*)$|} in
    let trailing = matches @@ Perl.compile_pat {|^(.*?)/*\*\*$|} in 
    let open Re.Group in
    match trailing line with
      | Some group -> Trailing (get group 1)
      | None -> match leading line with
      | Some group -> Leading (get group 1)
      | None -> match middle line with
      | Some group -> Middle ((get group 1), (get group 2))
      | None -> None

  let%test _ = double_asterisk "**/foo"     = Leading "foo"
  let%test _ = double_asterisk "foo/**"     = Trailing "foo"
  let%test _ = double_asterisk "foo/**/bar" = Middle ("foo", "bar")

  let getpath filename =
    let open Base in
    let open Re.Perl in
    let open Re in
      match exec_opt (compile_pat {|^(.*)/|}) filename with
        | None -> None
        | Some g -> Some (Re.Group.get g 1) (* <- ERROR HEERE *)

  let%test _ = getpath "foo/bar/tar" = Some "foo/bar" 

end
```

The problem where is that I override the None from `Option` module with the `double_asterisk` type. Now the compiler is treating every `None` as variant of `double_asterisk`. How can I specify from which type my variant is about?

I'm facing this error

```
File "git.ml", line 33, characters 20-24:
Error: This variant expression is expected to have type double_asterisk
       The constructor Some does not belong to type double_asterisk
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 4.08 you can qualify it as `Option.None`.

In earlier versions you can create a namespaced alias yourself, e.g.:

```
module MyOption = struct
  type 'a t = 'a option = None | Some of 'a
end

let _ = MyOption.None
```

But I would strongly recommend against overriding the constructors of built-in types. Consider using `Nothing` or some other equivalent term instead.